# Danger of Radon at the reference levels of 100Bq/m³ and 300Bq/m³

Tags: lungs, radon

In many regions of the earth there is a natural emission of radon, a radioactive gas, from the ground.  Radon can accumulate in houses and reach levels that are dangerous for human health leading to lung cancer.

The [WHO writes](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/radon-and-health)

> establishing a national annual average residential radon concentration reference level of 100 Bq/m³, but if this level cannot be reached under the prevailing country-specific conditions, the reference level should not exceed 300 Bq/m³;

Here in France  [the limit set by the government is 300Bq/m³](https://sante.gouv.fr/sante-et-environnement/batiments/article/qu-est-ce-que-le-radon)

> l’Organisation mondiale de la santé a recommandé un niveau de référence de 100 Bq/m³, et dans tous les cas de rester en deçà de 300 Bq/m³ (niveau qu’il est recommandé de ne pas dépasser). Le niveau de référence est de 300Bq/m³.

How have these levels be established?

In the French article it says that there are 3.000 deaths every year in France due to lung cancer produced by radon.  Still, this number alone does give me much information with respect to the radiation levels of 100 and 300Bq/m³ as it could very well be that the people that died had been exposed to 10,000Bq/m³ or more in their house and that there are very few people falling ill with lower levels.

Do you have any data allowing me to judge how dangerous radon really is at 100Bq/m³ and 300Bq/m³?

Thank you.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32400/acute-symptoms-from-radon-gas-exposure/32429#32429

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for Radon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon#References) has some pretty good references, including a [2006 report to the UN scientific committee on the effects of atomic radiation](https://www.unscear.org/unscear/uploads/documents/unscear-reports/UNSCEAR_2006_Report_Vol.I.pdf) (PDF) which you might want to peruse.